# Codeigniter controller attributes not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

so I was trying to save as an attribute of the class Profile.php the an specific uri segment but if I try this approach it doesn't work:

```
 private $section=$this->uri->segment(2);
```

But this gives me the error:

```
unexpected '$section' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)
```

I have it right after declaring the class.

I did try another thing which is working so fat but I'll have to do this in every single method I create and I kinda wanted to have it declared only in the attribute so I don-t have to repeat code:

```
private $section;

public function account(){
    $this->section=$this->uri->segment(2);
    $this->routedHome($this->section);
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can use constructor method for that

Comment: you can't setup the properties like that, do it inside the constructor

Comment: Right! thanks, I didn't even thought of that don't know why. Thanks, it obviously worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the __construct magic method. This is loaded on all requests.

```
<?php
class your_controller extends CI_Controller
{

    private $section;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->section=$this->uri->segment(2);
    }
}
```